# Python data to html table for loop

Tags: python, html, database, for-loop, flask

I'm working on a Python script which reads records from a database with sqlite3, and then needs to be displayed in a table on an HTML web page. I can't seem to understand how am I supposed to send the data from python to the HTML code, and then use it in an HTML for loop, so the table is as long as the amount of records in the database. I'm doing this with Python Flask. Any help would be appreciated!

Example of table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data 1.1</td>
        <td>some data 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some data 2.1</td>
        <td>some data 2.2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add the code you are running

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look into using templates with Flask ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/)). Please remember to include code that you have tried in your questions in future (and update this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from flask import render_template
import flask

yourdb=[
     ("your data 1.1","your data 1.2"),
     ("your data 2.1","your data 2.2"),
     ("your data 3.1", "your data 3.2")
     ]
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("index.html",data=yourdb)
```

And html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        İndex
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Your column Name 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Your Column Name 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{x[0]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{x[1]}}
        </td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

folder structure

```
--templates
|   |__index.html
|
--flashapp.py
```